# Sharing - E-mailing Input Fields

Tags: android, email, android-edittext, sharing

I am currently developing an app for the sales force at my company to use when out on the road. In addition to being a visual aid to displaying pictures of our products, I have included several calculators in the app that will allow for them to enter measurements and receive predetermined allowances.

What I am trying to do now, is have those same input fields (multiple EditText fields on different lines) into the message of an e-mail. I have the concept of how to compose an e-mail with the final address, subject line, and main message, but I don't currently know of any way to make the main message field populate with several EditText fields.

More than looking for code at the moment, I was just wondering if the group consensus was if this was possible or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You would just have to get the values of all edittext fields and then create a message in the format of your liking and put it in the body of email.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the String within the EditText `getText().toString()`, you can also generate EditTexts programatically, you can set the Message within any Textview or the hint or the text in the EditText programmatically.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I should have thought of that myself, as I sued several getText().toString()'s in the same script.

Comment: Glad it helped :)